# How to properly get window handle from EnumWindows WinAPI function?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, winapi

I'm trying to translate a C# piece of code to C++. The original C# code finds a window, which when drawn to will render below the icons on the desktop, so basically on, or rather instead of, the wallpaper. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the specific window handle back from the `EnumWindows()` function and its callback in order to draw on it.

Right now, I'm trying to pass a window handle pointer that is casted to an `LPARAM`:

```cpp
HWND workerw;
EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC)EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&workerw);
```

And then within the callback function I cast the LPARAM parameter back to a window handle:

```cpp
(HWND)workerw = FindWindowEx(0,hwnd,"WorkerW",0);
```

However when I run the program nothing happens, which makes me assume that I don't draw to the right window..

This is the whole file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Sleep(2000);
    HWND progman = FindWindow("ProgMan", NULL);

    // Send 0x052C to Progman. This message directs Progman to spawn a
    // WorkerW behind the desktop icons. If it is already there, nothing
    // happens.
    SendMessageTimeout(progman,0x052C,0,0,SMTO_NORMAL,1000,nullptr);

    HWND workerw;
    EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC)EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&workerw);

    HDC hdc = GetDC(workerw);
    if (hdc != NULL){
        TextOut(hdc, 20, 20, "hello world", 30);
    }else{
        cout << "error" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    RECT r = {0, 0, 1000, 1000};
    RedrawWindow(workerw, &r, NULL, RDW_NOERASE | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
    ReleaseDC(workerw, hdc);
    return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM workerw)
{
    HWND p = FindWindowEx(hwnd,0,"SHELLDLL_DefView",0);
    if (p != 0){
        // Gets the WorkerW Window after the current one.
        (HWND)workerw = FindWindowEx(0,hwnd,"WorkerW",0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And this is the relevant part of the original C# file I got from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/856020/%2FArticles%2F856020%2FDraw-Behind-Desktop-Icons-in-Windows-plus):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DrawBehindDesktopIcons
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Fetch the Progman window
            IntPtr progman = W32.FindWindow("Progman", null);

            IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;

            // Send 0x052C to Progman. This message directs Progman to spawn a
            // WorkerW behind the desktop icons. If it is already there, nothing
            // happens.
            W32.SendMessageTimeout(progman,
                                0x052C,
                                new IntPtr(0),
                                IntPtr.Zero,
                                W32.SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_NORMAL,
                                1000,
                                out result);

            IntPtr workerw = IntPtr.Zero;

            // We enumerate all Windows, until we find one, that has the SHELLDLL_DefView
            // as a child.
            // If we found that window, we take its next sibling and assign it to workerw.
            W32.EnumWindows(
                new W32.EnumWindowsProc((tophandle, topparamhandle) =>
                {
                    IntPtr p = W32.FindWindowEx(tophandle,
                                                IntPtr.Zero,
                                                "SHELLDLL_DefView",
                                                IntPtr.Zero);

                    if (p != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        // Gets the WorkerW Window after the current one.
                        workerw = W32.FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero,
                                                    tophandle,
                                                    "WorkerW",
                                                    IntPtr.Zero);
                    }

                    return true;
                }),
                IntPtr.Zero);

            // We now have the handle of the WorkerW behind the desktop icons.
            // We can use it to create a directx device to render 3d output to it,
            // we can use the System.Drawing classes to directly draw onto it,
            // and of course we can set it as the parent of a windows form.

            // Get the Device Context of the WorkerW
            IntPtr dc = W32.GetDCEx(workerw, IntPtr.Zero, (W32.DeviceContextValues)0x403);
            if (dc != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
                {
                    // Create a Graphics instance from the Device Context
                    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(dc))
                    {
                        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, 500, 500);
                    }
                }
                // make sure to release the device context after use.
                W32.ReleaseDC(workerw, dc);
            }
        }
    }
} // namespace DrawBehindDesktopIcons
```

When I compile and run the C# version, it works fine.

Of course, since I have no knowledge of C# whatsoever, it might as well be I am missing something totally obvious, if that's the case I apologize.

I hope someone can help me get this to work, it would make a lot of cool stuff possible!

In the end, I want to use facial detection and opencv to create the illusion of depth in my desktop background, an actual window sort of thing.

Comment: `*(HWND*)workerw = FindWindowEx(0,hwnd,"WorkerW",0);` must be. in original *c++* code error

Comment: That is actually what I had before, are you saying that this actually the right way to do it or that this is causing the error? :)

Comment: of course `(HWND)workerw = FindWindowEx` is logic error. you modify argument of function. no sense do this actually you have pointer to `HWND` argument. you need use `*(HWND*)workerw = FindWindowEx` code. i personally prefer declare another function `BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, HWND* phwnd)` and cast in call `EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC)EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&workerw);` (in your original code you not need cast `EnumWindowsProc` to `WNDENUMPROC` )

Comment: so with my declaration - use `*phwnd = FindWindowEx`.